# Sending email with firebase, sendgrid, angular

Tags: firebase, cors, http-headers, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I've tried to configure emailfunctionalities with firebase/sendgrid a my Angular-app. Function is called when hitting a button

```
**--INDEX.JS**  
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const SENDGRID_API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key

const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);


exports.httpEmail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) =>
{

  cors(req, res, () =>
  {

    const toName = req.body.toName;
    const toEmail = req.body.toEmail;

    const msg = {
      to: toEmail,
      from: 'hello@angularfirebase.com',
      subject: 'New Follower',
      // text: `Hey ${toName}. You have a new follower!!! `,
      // html: `<strong>Hey ${toName}. You have a new follower!!!</strong>`,

      // custom templates
      templateId: '300e1045-5b30-4f15-8c43-41754b73fe4f',
      substitutionWrappers: ['{{', '}}'],
      substitutions: {
        name: toName
        // and other custom properties here
      }
    };

    return sgMail.send(msg)

      .then(() => res.status(200).send('email sent!'))
      .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err))

  });

});


**--SendEmailComponent**
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RequestOptions } from 'http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-send-email',
  templateUrl: './send-email.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./send-email.component.css']
})
export class SendEmailComponent implements OnInit
{
  //fields
  endpoint = 'https://**blankblank**.cloudfunctions.net/httpEmail';
  httpOptions =
    {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      })
    }

  //ctr
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  //lifehook
  ngOnInit()
  {
  }

  //methods
  sendEmail()
  {
    const data =
      {
        toEmail: 'someone@something.net',
        toName: 'Some One'
      }

    //post
    this.http.post(this.endpoint, data, this.httpOptions).subscribe(data => console.log('email sent: ', data));
  }

}
```

I tried different [tutorials](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sendgrid-v3-nodejs-transactional-email-cloud-function/), but I always get this error:

> Failed to load
>   https://*blankblank*.cloudfunctions.net/httpEmail:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource

Answer (score 0):

You need to include dummy values for the text and html attributes for SendGrid. Also this is how the Cors method should look that I was able to get working

**index.js:**

```
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const sendGrid = require('@sendgrid/mail');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();
sendGrid.setApiKey(functions.config().sendgrid.apikey);
sendGrid.setSubstitutionWrappers('{{', '}}');

exports.sendBookingEmail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    cors(req,res, () => {

const message = {
  to: req.body.email,
  bcc: ['test@email.com'],
  from: 'test@email.com',
  text: 'email',
  html: '<strong>email</strong>',      
  substitutions: {
    contactName: 'test name',
    siteName: 'test site'
  }
} 

        sendGrid.send(message);
        res.status(200).send('email sent new');
    }); 

});
```

Comment: Hi Ben. Thanks for you comment and suggestions. Unfortunatly I'm not educated enough to translate this Angular 1 code to Angular 2. I'll have to look further in order to get the mailfunction running.

Comment: Hi @Emiel I've updated the solution to be more specific - the angular 1 code was only there for reference and I have now removed it. The reason you are having errors could be 1. no text or html attributes set in the sgMail.send method or 2. the way you have set up your cors in the function - as you are getting a CORS related error message